# What is this encoding

Tags: javascript, php, python, http, obfuscation

Check this url:
http://m.livescore.com/~~/app1-category/soccer/germany?tz=1&tzout=1

This should be json feed.
Probably encoded to gzip with timestamp in the beginning.

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Mar 2017 10:53:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Cache-Control: max-age=5
Pragma: cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Wed, 08 Mar 2017 10:53:37 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Mar 2017 10:53:32 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Disposition: filename=germany.JSON
Server: origin
X-Cached: HIT
content-length: 7277`

content looks like:

`Query-Expiry::: 2017-03-08 11:27:40Q0Ydk"KGF("Vdl"L=*"X\d"P=,"Z^__d"HM,"Z"EIm%#$K=GK("d"HH,"Z"EI6`M?IMJ"f"7?."\b__f"\@D-"[*g"FGJ>t"["OC5@N@x"i"CCn"*"SG9DH:;"m">=~"Y]e"4HIs"Z^f"+P

I tried to use gzip, but it complained it is not gzip.
I just wonder that somebody is familiar with this format and tell me what it is and how it is consumed in javascript.

Comment: @deceze  Too broad?? What do you need to know more?

Comment: 1) The question hinges exclusively on the contents of a 3rd party URL; once that goes away or changes, the question becomes worthless. 2) Have you tried narrowing it down? You already have a suspicion on what it is; have you tried to gunzip it after removing the timestamp? 3) If that's not it, we are just left to speculate and do random trial and error – not exactly what this site is for.

Comment: OK. I adjusted the question. Now you remove the mark.

Comment: You should look at the code that consumes it. It looks more like something regular (JSON?) XOR'ed with something. For instance, look at all those ''Zhp"s and other recurring stuff.

Comment: `fDd:function(a,b)` is what you're looking for in http://cdn1.livescore.com/webapp/js/custom.46a23d4d.js   Just prettify it and rip that func out. First param is the obfuscated text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the javascript functions `lsMobile.fn.charToInt, lsMobile.fn.fDk, lsMobile.fn.fDdCheckCharEx, lsMobile.fn.fDd` included from [here](http://cdn1.livescore.com/webapp/js/custom.46a23d4d.js) and then use any javascript engine to evaluate `json = lsMobile.fn.fDd(obfuscated, 1)`.

The resulting json will be something like `{"Stages":[{"Pid":1,"Events":[{"T1":[{"ID":8406,"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Augsburg"}],...`

Of course, the function names and the obfuscation method might change at random, whenever the server side re-runs whichever obfuscator they use.

Another approach which is more robust against changes in the obfuscation algorithm might be to render their site in a virtual DOM and scrape the content from there.

Comment: You might want to mention where to extract them from. There is also no guarantee that rendering the dom is more robust. The representation can change there as easily, requiring changes to the scraper.  And it's a lot more convoluted.

Comment: Included current script url and specified 'robustness'. Thanks @pvg !

Comment: np, thanks for typing all of it out and i'm sorry to keep nitpicking at you but if you lift out the functions, as you yourself are suggesting, their subsequent renaming and re-obfuscation doesn't matter as long as the functionality remains the same. There is no loss of robustness against changes in obfuscation.

Comment: @pvg I appreciate your thoughts. The (client-side application / android) obfuscators I dealt with so far do dynamically change their obfuscation pattern, e.g. not only the naming, but the implementation of `lsMobile.fn.fDd` would change on each subsequent deployment. That's an uneducated guess though, as I have no knowledge about the obfuscator used for their api here.

Comment: This particular function takes an entirely program-external input, does some munging and spits something out. An obfuscator (or optimizing compiler, or any other code transformation) can't change the behaviour 'for input X, give me Y'. That has to stay invariant or it's not an obfuscator but 'arbitrary bug introducer'. Which I guess would be one kind of _really_ powerful obfuscator.

Comment: @pvg ;) of course both server and client code would need to go through the same deployment pipeline where the obfuscation takes place. Could be a bit too far fetched, though, so OP might indeed have better luck following your advice.

Comment: Thanks guys both of you. I really appreciate it. This is definitely good approach. I am only confused that I dont see the file with the obfuscation to be download at all in my Chrome.